# How to call only one item from array with $this->config->item CODEIGNITER?

Tags: codeigniter, config

I have a default config file in my config directory (default.php). I've loaded it already with autoload file:

```
$autoload['config'] = array('default');
```

there is my default.php:

```
<?php

//$config['secretUserHashKey'] = 'g81h6JH18kASPkgAW16jS132sa186h1';
//$config['secretPhotoNameHashKey'] = 'ghOH3Hs841s98sssp1AHDWPfMHAjd';

// Pages

$config['pagesUrl'] = array(
    'home' => 'homepage',
    'login' => 'loginsite'
);
```

and how I should use it on my view?

```
<li><a href="<?=base_url($this->config->item('home'));?>">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
```

with this example I can get value if mine string is'nt array:

```
$config['home'] = 'homepage';
```

so what should I do to grab item from my array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $this->config->item('home', 'pagesUrl');?>
```

Comment: Why "try this"? Where is the educational explanation?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this way:

```
$api_config = ci()->config->item('api');
if (isset($api_config['api_server']))
...
```

or in your case:

```
$pagesUrl_config = ci()->config->item('pagesUrl');
if (isset(pagesUrl['home']))
...
```

or in the view:

```
<?= @base_url(@ci()->config->item('pagesUrl')['home'])?>
```

ci() is self-defined, in application/core/MY_Controller.php at the bottom.

```
function &ci(): MY_Controller {
    return MY_Controller::get_instance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
 $this->config->config['pagesUrl']['home']
```

Answer (score 0):

$this->config->item('item_name');

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html